# How to use interpolation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Could anyone help how should I use the interp1-function on MATLAB on data such as the following:

```
   -99
     3
     1
     7
    10
    10
    22
    29
   -99
   -99
    25
    26
    60
   142
    78
   124
    74
    26
    13
    18
```

The -99 data values correspond to error-values and I would like to interpolate them...advices? =) Thank you!

Comment: I have tried the following: If for example the value X = -99, I have made its value equal X = (X-1 + X+1)/2, but I was thinking if MATLAB's interp1-function could give me better results or something but the function is kind of mystery to me and I was thinking if I could get the answer here in 1 min instead trying to figure the function out 1 hour =)

Comment: Try reading `help interp1` before asking people to explain it to you.

Comment: I know what you mean and I tried that, but you know when you're busy and stressed you sometimes want to try your luck ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not around Matlab at the moment but I reckon you could do something like this:

```
    Y =  [-99
         3
         1
         7
        10
        10
        22
        29
       -99
       -99
        25
        26
        60
       142
        78
       124
        74
        26
        13
        18];

%Make an array of x values - I'm assuming yours are evenly spaced
Xi = 1:length(Y);

%remove the -99 points
errors = Y == -99;
X = Xi(~errors);
Y = Y(~errors);

Yi = interp1(X, Y, Xi);
```

So in the code X and Y are the x and y coord vectors of the points you want to interpolate, i.e. your input points (without the errors!), and Xi is a vector of the location of the points you would like to interpolate values for (if you think about X being location and Y being value). The point Yi will be the interpolated values corresponding to Xi, which I think in this case will be your original vector with the -99 points replaced by linearly interpolated values. Funny stuff might happen at the edges :/ check the docs. Hope there are no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your array is `a`.

```
x = find(a ~= -99);
y = a(x);
xi = 1:length(a);
yi =  interp1(x, y, xi);
```

`yi` is what you are looking for.